# MSVC 2010 error with Boost on /MT

Tags: visual-c++

I am currently having issue compiling my project with MSVC 2010 when /MT is enable in Code generation.

1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-sgd-1_51.lib'

If i do /MD it works fine but i want to do /MT so i can run the program on any pc.

i cannot seem to find the file "libboost_thread-vc100-mt-sgd-1_51.lib" even on the boost main website : http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.51.0-x64/

using bjam i tried : .\b2 --with-thread variant=release link=static threading=multi runtime-link=static

and still no go, same error as before...any idea how i can fix this?